# What is single user equivalent for /opt?

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure, home

I'm creating the installer for my application. The app comes with specific versions of some popular libraries and binaries (Tcl/Tk and Python), so I can't install it to standard locations.

If the app gets installed for all users, then the perfect location would be `/opt/<my-app-name>`, but what would be good default directory for single user installs?

I'm considering `~/apps/<my-app-name>`, but is there some kind of standard or convention for this? Where would you install eg. Eclipse if you didn't have root access?

Comment: I don't think this is a good question for this SE because it is subjective, but I could be wrong.. why not /opt/user, or /usr/user?

Comment: @ekaj a regular user doesn't have permission to write to either of those locations. I would recommend `~/local` or `~/.local`. `~/.local` is used by python `distutils/setuptools` when `--user` is used. `pip` should probably be your "installer" in this case.

Comment: good point @jordanm.

Comment: What is your reason for writing an installer instead of `pip` or `easy_install` (both support `--user`)?

Comment: @jordanm I want to use specific Python version compiled against specific Tcl/Tk version.

Comment: ugh. please don't. find another way to meet your goals. dont proliferate python sprawl. its already horrible as is.